# Round long from 1004L to 1000L (or 1006L to 1010L)

Tags: java, rounding, long-integer, modulo, integer-arithmetic

Suppose I have `Long someLong = 1004L`. What efficient method can I use to round this down to `1000L`? Note that I do not actually know that `someLong == 1004L` so I can't simply do `someLong -= 4L;`. I need a generalizable method. I also want the ability to round down to each `5` instead of each `10`, for example a function to round to `1005L` (since if we're rounding by `5`'s then it'll round up instead of down).

More examples .. It could be that I have `1926L` and I want to round to `5` meaning I need `1925L`. Or I need to round to `10` meaning I need `1930L`.

Comment: so 1007 should be round to 1005?

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many questions.

Comment: @KendallFrey Find one and we'll all vote to close...

Comment: For rounding to the nearest multiple of `x` (towards 0) you can simply use `(someLong / x) * x`.

Answer (score 7):

This is very simple.

**If you want to round always down**:

Your required formula is:

```
someLong-someLong%10
```

It is because `someLong%10` is the remainder of `someLong` divided by 10. If you get this from the original number, you get the downrounded value, which you wanted.

The generalization is also simple: you can use 100, or even 13, if you want.

If you want to rounding in another direction (for example, rounding always up or always to the middle), then first to add something to this number, and then round always down.

---

**If you want to round always up:**

Then first you need to first add 9, then round always down.

```
someLong+9-(someLong+9)%10
```

---

**If you want to round always to the middle:**

...also you want to round to the nearest neightbor. Then you first add the *half* of the required interval, then round always down. For example, for 10 it is:

```
someLong+5-(someLong+5)%10
```

Comment: `%100` would be appropriate if he just wants to round to the nearest thousand.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
double a=1002l;
double b=a/10;

a=Math.round(b)*10;

System.out.println("Double round of value : "+a);
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic function to round to the nearest multiple of `k` would be (works for positives only):

```
public static long round(long toRound, long k) {
    long times = toRound / k;
    long reminder = toRound % k;
    if (reminder < k / 2)  {
        return k * times;
    } else {
        return k * (times + 1);
    }
}
```

And a branchless variant (`reminder < k / 2` => `(2 * reminder / k) < 1`:

```
public static long round(long toRound, long k) {
    long times = toRound / k;
    long reminder = toRound % k;
    return k * (times + ((2 * reminder) / k));
}
```

Comment: I think you need to cast to `double` when you do those divisions

Comment: @user2763361 No, that is not required. It is deliberately integer division.

Comment: You don't. The invariant is that `times * k <= toRound` and `0 <= reminder < k`. The decision whether to return `times * k` or `(times + 1) * k` depends just on the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round a `value` towards the nearest multiple of `step` using the semantics of `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` (if exactly halfway between two steps, round up), the necessary calculations are:

```
val += step/2;
val -= val%step;
```

Comment: +1 This is a really neat solution. A two line method, whereas other answers require six or seven. (Including mine, now deleted).

Answer (score 1):

```
myFloor(long n, int m) {
  return n - (n % m);
}


myRound(long n, int m) {
  int i = (n % m) >= (m / 2) ? m : 0;
  return n + i - (n % m);
}
```

so `m` could be `10 , 5 , ...`

Answer (score 1):

The following example reachs what you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long n   = 1004L;
    Long n2  = 1005L;

    n = round(n);
    n2 = round(n2);

    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println(n2);
}

private static Long round(Long n) {
    if (n%10 <=4) {
        return n -=n%10;
    } else {
        return n += (10-n%10);
    }
}
```